# Why do I see this in the graph of $\ln(x) + i\pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

There is always a time when we realize that people telling us that “logarithms of negatives are undefined” is a lie.

With complex analysis, we can derive the following:

> As $e^{i\pi} = -1$,
> $\ln(-1) = i\pi$. Hence, $\ln(-|a|) = \ln|a| + i\pi(2k + 1)$ where $k \in Z$.

This is a pretty general result from complex analysis.

When I first derived this on my own, I curiously typed “$f(x) = \ln(x) + i\pi$” into GeoGebra Graphing calculator, and got this:

[[image: GeoGebra graphing calculator <span class=]$f(x) = \ln(x) + i\pi$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQRuf.jpg)

The first thing I noticed was that every line was at a right angle.

What in the world does this graph mean/imply? And why is GeoGebra plotting a function involving $i$ in the Cartesian plane?

Help is appreciated!

Edit: As Izaak Van Dongen asked, the following are some other functions plotted in GeoGebra:

$a(x) = x + \frac{1+i}{3}$:
[image: the above function]

$b(x) = x^2 - \frac{i}{2}$:
[image: the above function]

$c(x)=x^i - 1$:
[image]

$d(x) = x^{(2^i)}\sin(ix)i$:
[image]
This one is not at right angles.

$f(x) = e^{ix}$:
[image]
Here we can see how $e^{ix}$ (with initial condition $f(0) = 1$) can be thought of as walking around the unit circle.

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph: Negative numbers do have logarithms, but **the** logarithm of a negative number is undefined. Much like how negative numbers have square roots, but $\sqrt{-1}$ is nonsensical.

Comment: It looks like Geogebra is showing you what happens to the grid-lines at integer $x$ and $y$ coordinates when $f$ is applied (thinking of the $xy$ plane as the complex plane). See what happens if you type something like $f(x) = x + \frac{1 + i}3$, for example. The reason you see right angles is because of the fact "a complex-differentiable function with nonzero derivative at $z$ is conformal at $z$" (roughly, because $f$ has a nonzero derivative, it behaves locally like rotating and scaling, and hence right angles remain as right angles).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks for the answer! I shared some more graphs in the question.

Comment: +1 because I didn't know Geogebra was able to do this. Arthur and Izaak have great answers.

Comment: Aw man I got excited thinking Desmos had complex number abilities natively and I just missed it for years. It makes sense that Geogebra has more functionality on this front.

Comment: @Arthur I wonder if there's a difference in notation, that **the** logarithm may mean **the principal value** of the natural log?

Answer (score 0):

A $\ln$ function can certainly be defined on $\mathbb R$ in a natural way.  In fact, one can even define its derivative on $\mathbb R$.  For a detailed discussion, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/127601/28128).

Comment: I do not really agree because of the article «the» in your message. The $\ln$ notation refers to the function we all know defined on $\mathbb R_{>0}$. If one wishes to speak of an extension to the entire real line, then one can do so by distributions or by a determination of the complex logarithm. In the latter two cases, the same notation should not be used unless mention is made of the extension (which is not essentially unique).